# Start a download with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I have some code that makes a button appear after the progress bar has gotten to the end. But I would prefer it if it started a download instead of someone having to click the button to download it. How would i go about doing this?

This is the code I'm currently using to open a button:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn-success").hide();
    var progress = setInterval(function () {
        var $bar = $('.progress-bar');
        if ($bar.width() >= 399) {
            clearInterval(progress);
            $(".btn-success").show("slow");
            $('.progress').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $bar.width($bar.width() + 40);
        }
    }, 115);
});
</script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <h1 style="text-  align: center; margin-top: -5px;">Thanks for downloading!</h1>
        <h3 style="color: gray; text-  align: center; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: -20px;">Shixmas website source code</h3>  
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 3%; width: 400px;">
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button_align_download">
        <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Download</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 3%;">
    <a href="/downloads">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top:1%;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Go Back To Downloads
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the download link in this example? What the "Download" button does? You need to call exactly the same thing that happens when the user click in the Download button. If you don't show us what it does, we can't help ya.

Comment: ^^^ What he said, it's not very clear why clicking the button would start a download ?

Comment: Oh wait, did you stick a button inside an anchor ?

Comment: The button that starts the actual download is this: <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Download</button></a>

Comment: That's great, but how does it start the download ?

Comment: The jquery doesn't start the download, it just brings up a hidden download button. Typically you would just make a download like this wouldnt you: <a href="/test/test.zip">Download</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to simply use `window.location = '/downloads/file.jpg';`

You then need to configure your server to send a header that instructs the browser to download that file instead of opening it in the window.

If you're using Apache you can add this to a `.htaccess` file. Using the following configuration, you can put all your downloads in the "downloads" folder and they will all download instead of opening.

This is just an example of course, you can set this up how you like.

```
<Location "/downloads/">
  <Files *.*>
    ForceType applicaton/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
  </Files>
</Location>
```